# Express baseUrl param not available

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Let's say I have the following routes:

```
// routes.js
import PhotoRoutes from './photoRoutes';

const UserBaseRoute = Router();
UserBaseRoute.use('/api/:userId', PhotoRoutes);

// photoRoutes.js
const PhotoRoute = Router();
PhotoRoute.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params);
    res.end();
});

export default PhotoRoute;
```

When I hit `/api/123/` I expect to use `{"userId: 123}'` But I don't. Why is the `:userId` defined in the baseRoute not passed up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a issue related to nested router.
You need to set the **mergeParams** of child router as **true** to access **params** from parent router.

So try following code:

```
const PhotoRoute = Router({mergeParams: true});
```

BTW, this option came with **Express** version 4.5. For more details, refer to the [API document](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html)